# Generating an action URL in JavaScript for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to redirect to another page by calling an action in controller with a specific parameter. I'm trying to use this line:

```
window.open('<%= Url.Action("Report", "Survey",
    new { id = ' + selectedRow + ' } ) %>');
```

But I couldn't make it work; it gives the following error:

> `CS1012: Too many characters in character literal.`

Can't I generate the action URL this was on the client side? Or do I have to make an Ajax call by supplying the parameter and get back the needed URL? This doesn't seem right, but I want to if it's the only way.

Is there an easier solution?

Comment: Is it a JS error? What is rendered html-result?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Remember that everything between <% and %> is interpreted as C# code, so what you're actually doing is trying to evaluate the following line of C#:

```
Url.Action("Report", "Survey", new { id = ' + selectedRow + ' } )
```

C# thinks the single-quotes are surrounding a character literal, hence the error message you're getting (character literals can only contain a single character in C#)

Perhaps you could generate the URL once in your page script - somewhere in your page HEAD, do this:

```
var actionUrl =
    '<%= Url.Action("Report", "Survey", new { id = "PLACEHOLDER" } ) %>';
```

That'll give you a Javascript string containing the URL you need, but with PLACEHOLDER instead of the number. Then set up your click handlers as:

```js
window.open(actionUrl.replace('PLACEHOLDER', selectedRow));
```

i.e. when the handler runs, you find the PLACEHOLDER value in your pre-calculated URL, and replace it with the selected row.

Comment: I don't know if it will help you, but this question/answer helped me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093977/razor-mvc3-jquery-urlaction-partialviews/5094357#5094357

Answer (score 10):

I usually declare a javascript variable in the  section to hold the root of my website.

```
<%="<script type=\"text/javascript\">var rootPath = '"
    + Url.Content("~/") + "';</script>" %>
```

To solve your problem I would simply do

```
window.open(rootPath + "report/survey/" + selectedRow);
```

Comment: Simple and effective. On a razor page I needed to use  `<script type="text/javascript">
  var rootMvcPath = '@Url.Content("~/")';
 </script>`

Answer (score 3):

Could you do

```
window.open('/report/survey/' + selectedRow);
```

instead where selected row I assume is the id? The routing should pick this up fine.

or use getJSON

Perhaps you could use JSONResult instead. Wherever the window.open should be call a method instead i.e. OpenSurveyWindow(id);

then add some jquery similar to below

```
function OpenSurveyWindow(id){
      $.getJSON("/report/survey/" + id, null, function(data) {
          window.open(data);
     });
}
```

now in your controller

```
public JsonResult Survey(int id)
{
    return Json(GetMyUrlMethod(id));
}
```

That code isnt syntactically perfect but something along those lines should work

Comment: But I want the url to be generated by the Url.Action because this way I also have the specify the url root parameters which can change!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works but in order get a simple route making an ajax call doesn't seem OK to me. But if there wasn't any other way I would do it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Just if someone is still looking for this. The controller action can have normal parameters or a model object with these fields. MVC will bind the valus automatically.

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';
 $.post(url, {
      YearId: $("#YearId").val(),
      LeaveTypeId:  $("#LeaveTypeId").val()
 }, function (data) {
      //Do what u like with result
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this that might be considered cleaner involves using the [T4MVC T4 templates](https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/). You could then write the JavaScript inside your view like this:

```
var reportUrl = '<%= Url.JavaScriptReplacableUrl(MVC.Survey.Report())%>';
reportUrl = myUrl.replace('{' + MVC.Survey.ReportParams.id + '}', selectedRow);

window.open(reportUrl);
```

The advantage of this is that you get compile-time checking for the controller, action, and action parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do this, the URL.Action is a server side process so will parse before the clientside selectedRow is available. Israfel has the answer I would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If selectedRow is a client-side variable, it won't work.  You have to use @Israfel implementation to link.  This is because the server-side runs before the client-side variable even exists.

If selectedRow is a server-side variable within the view, change to this:

window.open('<%= Url.Action("Report", "Survey", new { id = selectedRow } ) %>');

This is because the id will infer the selectedRow variable type, or you could convert to string with ToString() method (as long as it's not null).

Answer (score 0):

One more thing that can be done, no so clean i guess:

```
var url = "@Url.RouteUrl(new { area = string.Empty, controller = "Survey", action = "Report" })";
var fullUrl = url  + '?id=' + selectedRow;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to declare a javascript variable than concate your parameter value to the link.

```
  var url = '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")' + "/" + yourjavascriptvariable;
  <a href='" + url + "'>
```