# Razor mvc3 + jquery + UrlAction + PartialViews

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a question about jQuery + Razor.. I want to build a javascript variable using razor with @Url.Action and the html attributes will be values of inputs.
Like this:

`var d1 = $('#d1').val();`
`var d2 = $('#d2').val();`
`var url = "@Url.Action("Links", "PartialAccount", new { beginDate = "d1", endDate = "d2" })"`
`$("#links").fadeOut("slow").load(url).fadeIn("slow");`

How can I do this?

Is it the same that below?
`var url = "/PartialAccount/Links/?beginDate=" + d1 + "&endDate=" + d2;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)  method as proposed by InfernalBadger:

```
load('@Url.Action("Links", "PartialAccount")', { beginDate: d1, endDate: d2})
```

because this will encode the parameters in `d1` and `d2` correctly. But only if you can pass the parameters as part of the querystring, not when they should be a part of the url itself.

So you can use if you want your url to be:

```
 /bar/foo?beginDate=1-1-2001&endDate=2-2-2001
```

(note that the /'s in the date will be encoded)

You cannot use this if you want your url to be:

```
/bar/foo/1-1-2001/2-2-2001
```

The `@Url` method, with the beginDate and endData parameters, does not work, because this is executed on the server, before the page is send to the browser.

And your method by using the `+` operator fails the user enters "special characters" in the input boxes (like dashes /).

Answer (score 4):

I would pass the two values via the data parameter of load() if you want to get the values from dom elements?

```
$("#links").fadeOut("slow").load(url, { beginDate: d1, endDate: d2}).fadeIn("slow");
```