# Passing parameter to controller via jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i cannot seem to find a way to pass a Parameter to my controller via jquery.

Code i currently have, The Id field below needs to take a parameter numSelected which does not work for some reasons. Error: Type expected

```
   $.get('<%= Url.Action("getPart","Reservation", new (Id = 'numSelected'))%>', function (data) {
             $('#ExtraBox').replaceWith(data);
         });
```

The function being called in controller

```
public ActionResult getPart(int id)
    {
        ViewData["testID"] = id;

        return PartialView("test");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function EditTrip(id) {
    var id2 = 0;
    top.location.href = "/Home/TripLog/" + id + "/" + id2;
}
```

Comment: here Home is the controller and TrigLog is the action

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fiddler or chrome development tools to get the actual url your ajax call makes, then verify the path to make sure you are calling the right controller/action/route.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your syntax being wrong, you're trying to mix client-side and server-side code.  See [Generating an action URL in JavaScript for ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012610/generating-an-action-url-in-javascript-for-asp-net-mvc) for a solution.