# Can not access variable from @Url.Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this Javascript in a ASP.Net MVC page

```
onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {
        $('#divImgs ul').append(
            $('<li>').append(
            $('<a>').attr('href', 
                '@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Upload", new { id = fileName})').append(
            $('<img>').attr('src', responseJSON.filePath))
         ));
     }
 }
```

This gives Compilation error

```
The name 'fileName' does not exist in the current context
```

Why can't I access `fileName` variable within the `@Url.Action`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is that @Url.Action is resolved server side while filename is a javascript variable on the client side. You're best bet is something like this:

```
onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {
        $('#divImgs ul').append(
            $('<li>').append(
            $('<a>').attr('href', '@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Upload", new { id = "' + filename + '" })').append(
            $('<img>').attr('src', responseJSON.filePath))
         ));
     }
}
```

There might be a better way to append the filename to the url, but the idea here is to render out the base url from the server, then modify it as needed with the javascript.

EDIT: I agree with haim77. You need to have the route be rendered server side instead of just appending on the client side in case the format of the route changes. But in this case, we need to inject some javascript. So just inject the variable into the route so it resolves to the right format, but also outputs javascript compatible code.

Comment: This approach may not generate the correct url as registered in the routing collection. there could be a registered route that would match only certain pattern (like `/Upload/DeleteFile/filename.jpg`).

Comment: The point is to generate the base of the url and append according to your own needs. You would get '/Upload/DeleteFile' and from there, append either '?id=' or '/filename'.

Comment: Well, if you already know whether the url to your action uses `?id=` or `/filename` then `Url.Action` is almost redundant.

Comment: Did a little googling. This has already been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012610/generating-an-action-url-in-javascript-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

Because `filename` is a JavaScript variable that only exists in the client-side, while `@Url.Action` is executed (beforehand) in the server-side when the `View` renders itself.

To solve the problem, i usually do something like:

```
@object URL_ACTION_PLACEHOLDER = "__MYPLACEHOLDER__";

// ...

onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.success) {
        var myActionUrl = '@Url.Action("DeleteFile", "Upload", new { id = URL_ACTION_PLACEHOLDER })';
        myActionUrl = myActionUrl.replace('@URL_ACTION_PLACEHOLDER', fileName);

        $('#divImgs ul').append(
            $('<li>').append(
            $('<a>').attr('href', myActionUrl).append(
            $('<img>').attr('src', responseJSON.filePath))
         ));
     }
 }
```