# Passing parameters to javascript functions

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some buttons that are created from a list, so when the button is created i do the following:

```
<button id="@objClass.Id.ToString()"onclick="EditClass(this.id)">Edit</button>
```

once the button is clicked the following code is run. everything works great when i hard code a value in for clicked_id inside the url.action. My question is how to get the value passed from the EditClass function into my url.action.

```
function EditClass(clicked_id) 
{
    $('#editClassView').dialog(
    {
        modal: true,
        position: ['top', 'center'],
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function (clicked_id) 
        {
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Update", "Class", new { area = "manager", nClassId = clicked_id })",
            function (response, status, xhr) 
            {
                $('#editClassView').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
        }
    });

    $('#editClassView').dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: The code in the line of `$(this).load` is all messed up (quotes). I'm not familiar with Razor, but it looks like this is code run on the server side, the correct URL is actually generated on the server side and doesn't have a access to the `clicked_id` which only exists on the client. But there might be helper methods to generate "dynamic" routes, I don't know.

Comment: Felix is right. This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012610/generating-an-action-url-in-javascript-for-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I looked right through that being generated on the server side. I guess I need to do my redirect in the client side javascript.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: CS0103: The name 'clicked_id' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Just after the url, in the loaf function, you could pass an object of your data.
So...

```
 var data = { my_variable: "value"};
 $(this).load(url, data, function (response, status, xhr) {
    $('#editClassView').dialog('open');
    return false;
 });
```